# Rails ActiveRecord and active_admin and transactions with remote database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I want to work with database (mysql) via remote connection (over ssh for example). I would like to know is ActiveRecord use transactions? Is transactions used when ActiveAdmin save nested related objects? Is it possible to data inconsistance occure when connection lose? What is the options (and how) to check for enable transactions for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter you're connecting to your remote DB via directly or via SSH as to how/whether the DB uses transactions. The ORM/DB isn't concerned with the specific details of the network connection so long as a connection is present.

Also, ActiveAdmin doesn't decide how transactions are applied. Typically transactions are used when creating records in Rails, including for nested objects, so the child object won't be saved if the parent object doesn't save. However, there can be exceptions to this depending on how you declare your associations in ActiveRecord.

In any case, the best way to verify transactions are working is to check your application logs. Look for `BEGIN` `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` statements which indicate specific SQL statements that are wrapped in transactions.